# Yahoo finance chart - interpreting bid and ask values

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges

The market is currently closed, and here is the chart for the previous trading day for AAPL.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL

Next to "bid" it says: 0.00 x 800

Next to "ask" it says: 0.00 x 900

Since the market is closed, what do these values refer to? Are these limit orders currently placed for the market open? Also it was my understanding the bid-ask spread is usually quite tight?

A further question: the graph indicates an opening price of 267.1, but in the summary it says the open was 263.75, quite a large difference. Which number is correct?

I've searched around on Yahoo site and can't find the information. New to all this so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The regular market may be currently closed but stocks trade during the pre-market (4-9:30 AM EST)  and during after hours (4-8 PM).  Your Yahoo chart is only displaying regular session information.

Right this minute, the real time quote is:

$276.50 x 100

$276.88 x 800

That means that someone is looking to buy 100 shares at $276.50 and other(s) are looking to sell 800 shares at $276.88

When I click your link it shows:

Bid = 279.80 x 800

Ask = 275.95 x 900

The bid is higher than the ask.  It's bad data.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused. I get what the data means when the session is open. But when the market is closed are the bid and ask values listed from the past session that got filled, or orders for when the market opens? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think that all of the data listed is from the regular session except for the after hours quote along with the time of that after hours quote.